# Why program do double output?

Tags: c

```
do
{
    randomNum = (topBorder + lowBorder)/2;

    printf("Your number is: %d?\n",randomNum);
    printf("My number is(larger-l/smaller-s/correct-c): ");

    scanf("%c", &compare);

    printf("\n");
    if (compare == 's') {
        topBorder = randomNum;
    }
    else if (compare == 'l') {
        lowBorder=randomNum;
    }
    else if (compare == 'c') {
        printf("I like that you take my number.\n");
        return 0;
    }
} while (compare = 1);
```

1. Program work correct but I do not know why write double time *Your number is: (number) My number is(...):

   ```
   ./pcIsUser

   Please, guess number between 1 and 100.
   Your number is: 50?

   My number is(larger-l/smaller-s/correct-c): l

   ***Your number is: 75? My number is(larger-l/smaller-s/correct-c):***

   Your number is: 75?
   My number is(larger-l/smaller-s/correct-c): s

   ***Your number is: 62?
   My number is(larger-l/smaller-s/correct-c):*** 
   Your number is: 62?
   My number is(larger-l/smaller-s/correct-c): c

   I like that you take my number.
   ```

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's difficult to diagnose what the problem(s) might be by looking at partial code.

Comment: User types `s` Enter `l` Enter `c` Enter.  That is 6 keystrokes and 6 `char`, not 3.  Add `else printf("%d"\n", compare);` to see the code of that `char`s that the program is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem

```
while (compare = 1)
```

it's assigning `1` to `compare`.

You need

```
while (compare == 1)
```

and you will never get a `1` from `scanf()` so perhaps just

```
while (compare)
```

works, also

```
scanf("%c", &compare);
```

is taking the previous `'\n'` left in the `stdin`, so this

```
scanf(" %c", &compare);
```

would explicitly skip whitespaces and solve the problem.

You should also `check` the returned value of `scanf()` to ensure that nothing unexpected happened like someone sending `EOF` via pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> on Windows.

Comment: Now its a complete answer.

Comment: I am looking most of C questions on SO since feb15 and the number is such mistakes is large.

Comment: @Vagish It's very likely the most common kind of mistake.